# Rows to mimic Columns

Tags: sql, relational-database, rdbms

I want to structure a table to mimic column level filters as row level filter just to avoid adding new columns.

Let's say i have following table to store cars' details

```
-------------------------------------
Type        Color       Year
-------------------------------------
Mini        Silver      2010
Standard    Silver      2011
Fullsize    White       2011
Luxury      Black       2010
Sports      Red     2011
Convertible Red     2009
```

If i want to store `Make` of these cars as well and for this i have to add an additional column and another column if i have automobiles other than cars.

So the question is how can i structure this table to avoid adding new columns? The structure should require only to add rows to define properties of my records.

[Hint] The structure may have multiple tables, one to store rows/records and other to store columns/properties and then some kind of mapping between them OR entirely new structure.

**EDIT**

Some of the properties of my data are fixed and some are dynamic. Fixed properties can be mapped to the given sample Car model as Availability, Condition and the dynamic could be anything which a person may ask about an automobile. Now i don't need all columns to be mapped as rows but few and these are dynamic and i don't even know all of them. My apologies that i didn't mention this earlier.

Comment: Hint? Are you giving us homework?

Comment: No, not at all :) Just wanted to mention that it could consist of multiple tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) design (EAV).

```
entity  attribute   value
1       Type        Mini
1       Color       Silver
1       Year        2010
1       Make        Foobar
2       Type        Standard
2       Color       Silver    
etc...
```

You may also wish to store the attribute names in a separate table.

However you should consider carefully if you *really* need this, as there are a few disadvantages. The value column must have a type that can store all the different types of values (e.g. string). It is much more cumbersome to write queries as you will need many joins, and these queries will run more slowly as compared to a traditional database design.

Comment: It's good that you put a strong warning label on that. I just read about the [Inner Platform Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_platform).

Comment: can you give me an example if i want to find an entity by its attributes?

Comment: EAV design might be suitable for storing and listing entities but anything based on their attributes like searching would require complex queries and these are harder to build as well, as you have already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

To give you a head start: Think about redesigning to allow multi-colored vehicles like motorbikes:

**vehicle**

```
Id    Year    vehicle_type    vehicle_make
-------------------------------------------
1     2010    1               1
2     2011    2               2
```

**color**

```
Id    Name
-----------
1     Black
2     White
3     Red
4     Blue
```

**vehicle_color**

```
vehicle_id    color_id
-----------------------
1             3
2             1
2             2
```

**vehicle_type**

```
Id    Name
-----------
1     Car
2     Motorbike
```

**vehicle_make**

```
Id    Name
-----------
1     Porsche
2     BMW
```

---

**Bonus**

Since I'm quite familiar with the car domain, I'll throw in an extension for your vehicle colors: There are tons of color names ("Magentafuzzyorangesunset") invented by manufacturers and you'll want to map them to "real" base color names ("Red, "Blue", "Green", etc.) to enable searching for both.

Your `color` table then could look like that

```
Id    Name        base_color
-----------------------------
1     Midnight    1
2     Snow        2
```

and you'll add a **base_color** table

```
Id    Name
-----------
1     Black
2     White
```

Comment: How would you store Make and CC? I dont think it is replacing columns with rows

Comment: I omitted *Make* because it could stay in `vehicle`. If by *CC* you are refering to *Color* - I moved it to the `vehicle_color` relation. This means you will have to `JOIN` `vehicle` and `vehicle_color` to retrieve all information about your car/motorbike.

Comment: I added the *Make* but you should get the idea by now - when you need to add colors to your vehicle you won't have to add colums like `color1`, `color2`, etc. to your `vehicle` table but just add rows to the vehicle_color relation.